# <p class="navbar-text">The World Awaits You</p>

Tags: php, html

please assist, I would like to add this The World Awaits You

below my logo on wordpress site. where do i add additional html on header.php, i am not familiar with php at all.

Comment: please be more specific about what you want to do and what problem you are facing?

Comment: thanks Aniket, i tried adding the site title and tagline but it all appears on the browser not below the logo as  want it to be

Comment: Darsh, i would like to a slogan below my logo but how do i add additional html in php? <p class="navbar-text">The World Awaits You</p> this is the code i want to add

Comment: can you show that where you want to add the text in screenshot?? also please show your header.php code.

Answer (score 1):

The best is probably to share your header.php code (it can be different for every theme..) and maybe make a picture of how it exactly should look like...
Taking the header.php from the current twentytwelve theme https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/header.php 
the easiest approach is to write your "The World Awaits You" into line 39

```
<h2 class="site-description">The World Awaits You</h2>
```

Comment: So it's this https://de.wordpress.org/themes/shop-isle/ theme? You should edit your original question in order to post the complete code to everyone. Currently I don't know the theme in detail, they use some actions and currently I don't have the time to look through in detail... maybe try your code after the `<header ...>` tag, after `<?php do_action( 'shop_isle_header' ); ?>` or before the `</header>` tag.